# Javascript - setHours() for cookie not working

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am creating a cookie that expires at 4 PM each day. I have a `setHours()` function that is supposed to set the cookie's expiration time to `16:00:00 PM` but instead sets the hours to `12:00:00 PM`. Could anybody tell me why it is doing this? Code used is below:

```
var date = new Date();
var expire = new Date();

// Check if time is before midnight but after blackout
if (date.getHours() >= 16 && date.getHours() <= 23) {
    expire.setFullYear(date.getFullYear());
    expire.setMonth(date.getMonth());
    expire.setDate(date.getDate()+1);
    expire.setHours(16);
    expire.setMinutes(0);
}

// Check if time is after midnight but before blackout
else if (date.getHours() >= 0 && date.getHours() < 11) {
    expire.setFullYear(date.getFullYear());
    expire.setMonth(date.getMonth());
    expire.setDate(date.getDate());
    expire.setHours(16);
    expire.setMinutes(0);
}

// Create a disabled order cookie
document.cookie = "OrderDisabled=true; expires=" + expire.toString() +"; path=/";
console.log(expire.toString());
```

Comment: Does the console show any errors?

Comment: @Script47 No errors. This is the entire console: `Mon Jul 11 2016 16:00:25 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`. The cookie says it expires at: `Monday, July 11, 2016 at 12:00:25 PM`

Comment: Try `expires.toUTCString()` see if this is the correct formatting

Comment: I think its your gmt problem

Comment: After trying the `.toUTCString()` validate that the string can use the `encodeURIComponent()` function. I'm pretty sure you can't have spaces, which you do.

Comment: @ChrisClark That was the issue! Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisClark can you explain what problem is `encodeURIComponent()` that doesn't exists in the original code?